# Angular - ng-disabled not working after scope change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input and a button. I want the button to be disabled when the input is empty or is more than 15 characters long.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="addCustomer" ng-model="customerNumber">
<button id="addSingleCustomerButton" ng-disabled="!isValidSingleInput(customerNumber)" ng-click="addCustomer()"></button>
```

**isValidSingleInput**

```
$scope.isValidSingleInput = function(input) {
    return (input != undefined && input.length > 0 && input.length <= 15);
}
```

**addCustomer**

```
$scope.addCustomer = function() {
    $('#addSingleCustomerButton').button('loading');

    // Call service to add customer number to database
    CustomerService.add({}, payload, function(data) {
        $('#addSingleCustomerButton').button('reset');
        $scope.customerNumber = '';
    });
}
```

At the end of the `addCustomer` function the input field is cleared by setting the scope with `$scope.customerNumber = '';`.

However, the button is not disabled again after clearing the input. I added a log to the `isValidInput` function with the result of it and it returns `false` after clearing the input. So the function is called and it returns the expected value, but it somehow has no effect on the button's `ng-disabled`.

**EDIT:** Added function `addCustomer`

**EDIT2:** Didn't think it would matter, but the problem is caused by Bootstrap's button.js. If I remove the `.button('loading')` and `.button('reset')` it's working. In my eyes this should work anyways because I'm resetting the scope after the button.

Comment: show more code....because I have copied your code and tried here its working fine!

Comment: edited my question

Comment: You can try this ---> http://jsfiddle.net/c_Dhananjay/ugchy8ew/17/ ?

Comment: Yeah, sure I could implement the `.button()` functionality by hand, but I think it should work as is...

Answer (score 1):

can you check to see why it might not be working for you?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    $scope.isValidSingleInput = function(input) {
    return (input != undefined && input.length > 0 && input.length <= 15);
 }
    $scope.addCustomer = function(){
     $scope.customerNumber = '';
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<input type="text" id="addCustomer" ng-model="customerNumber">
<button id="addSingleCustomerButton" ng-disabled="!isValidSingleInput(customerNumber)" ng-click="addCustomer()">BUTTON</button>

</div>
```

Comment: The difference in my case is that I have an asynchronous call to save the customer number in a database. The input is then cleared in the callback.